# NET Core: How do I inject multiple services into a controller?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Please bear with me if I have misunderstood something fundamental, but...

Assuming a Controller need **several** dependency injected services, like a DBContext, an AutoMapper, maybe some other registered service (of course properly registered in the Startup class), is that possible?

Pseudo-code for a single injected service:

```
class MyController 
{
    private DBContext _context;

    MyController(DBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }    
}
```

But if I need several services, like (again just pseudo code):

```
class My2ndController 
{
    private DBContext _context;
    private IMapper _mapper;
    private SomeConfig _config;

    My2ndController(DBContext context, IMapper mapper, SomeConfig config)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _config = config;
    }    
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that is how dependency injection works. If the amount of similar type interfaces becomes too much you can use an aggregate interface which houses it's own dependencies before passing to along as a single dependency.

Comment: Great book on this topic: https://www.amazon.com/Dependency-Injection-Principles-Practices-Patterns/dp/161729473X/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=Dependency+injection+.net+core&qid=1573598133&sr=8-4

Comment: _of course properly registered in the Startup class_ - fi so, then yes it is possible. Don't need to  ask just try ;)

Comment: Many thanks for your replies. So assuming I have registered my three services properly in Startup, can I use the My2ndController constructor above with the three input parameters and assume that all services are injected..?

Comment: As was answered already, yes. And again, you could have tested it yourself and saw it working in less time than it took to write this question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's possible,  you'll just need to make sure you register your service in your `Startup.cs`.

In your ConfigureServices method:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     // . . . code above

    services.AddTransient<IMapper, Mapper>();

    /// . . . code below
}
```

Now any controller that requires an `IMapper` interface will be passed the `Mapper` class upon creation.

Also, just know there are other lifetimes besides Transient.  Such as Singleton, where there can only be 1 instance of that class.

Comment: Thanks for you kind reply, but the question was: If I need SEVERAL services at the creation of the controller, could I use the constructor as in My2ndController above? Just specify all the services I want injected? ONE service is a no brainer, but SEVERAL?

Comment: Yes. I dont know if theres an upper limit, but so long as you register them you can have several.